# Git version is 2.3 but IntelliJ supports 2.9+

Tags: git, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image: Screenshot_0]

I have recently downloaded the newer version of IntelliJ Ultimate Idea and the newest Git 2.3 from the website. However, It is saying the IDEA can support only 2.9+? How is it possible if it is not available?

Comment: 2.3 is different to 2.30 - version numbers aren't decimals.

Comment: So how should I resolve this bug and connect the IDEA to git?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think the bug is.

Comment: **Is** there a bug or **do you think** there is a bug? Is there something you can't do?

Answer (score 3):

> in terminal, run 'sudo xcodebuild -license' and then agree to the
> terms.

Found answer [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241205-Mac-OSX-can-t-start-Git-after-updating-Mac-OS-XCode), worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

As is evidenced by your screenshot, you are running Git version 2.30.0, which is, in fact, greater than 2.9.

Answer (score -1):

Update your Git Version

Windows:

1. look for  Git Bash and open it
2. enter git update

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=unsupported+git+version+#kpvalbx=_cBL3ZMXvG8-WkwWpr6PgCw_32

Comment: Why do you expect that to help?

Comment: Yunnosch coz it worked for me after updating my git

Comment: I see, so random tinkering, the technical details and reasons of which you have no idea about, you applied to your git setup and - surprise - it helped. Thank you for bravely taking that risk. Of course, everbody using this unexplained method still takes the same risk, because their situation might be subtly different.